# Need to automatically switch a 12v 1amp dc pulse between 2 alternating outputs

Tags: switches, dc

I have a control unit that produces two 12v 1amp dc pulses lasting about 200ms. 
There is a gap of about 100ms between the pulses

I need to automatically switch these pulses between 2 outputs alternatly.

Any help would greatly appreciated

Comment: what is your device for controlling? are you use micro controller? Are you use TTL palse for selecting? Please explain your needs for selecting two outputs.

Comment: one output goes to one solonoid next output to go to another solonoid

Answer (score 3):

Use a D-flipflop like the [HEF4013](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/HEF4013B.pdf) to switch between channels.

[image]

With each pulse the high level switches between \$Q\$ and \$\overline{Q}\$ and back. AND each output with the input pulse signal. Use the AND gates' outputs to drive MOSFETs like the [FDC855](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/FD/FDC855N.pdf).

The HEF4013 is from the older CD4000 series, and normally I would suggest the [74HC74](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT74.pdf), but that one can't operate at 12 V. The HEF4013 can operate at a power supply voltage up to 15 V.

Don't forget the protection diodes across the solenoids.

Comment: Did you draw those schematics, if yes, using what?

Comment: @abdullah - Adobe Illustrator.

Comment: @abdullah - Illustrator is a fine software once you know how to use it. With "snap to grid" enabled is the timing diagram a question of minutes. As a matter of fact, the overscore over the "Q" was the most work :-)

Comment: I am wondering if there are dedicated programs that will create timing diagrams.

Comment: @abdullah - [TimingDesigner](https://www.ema-eda.com/Products/EMADesignAutomation/TimingDesigner.aspx), *only* 6500 dollar :-).

Comment: Oh, cheap! :) I wonder what semiconductor companies use when they design for datasheets, this one seems to be OK for them. Oh, [look](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/3564/5035) what I've found  :)

Answer (score -2):

One solution for this is using multiplexers. A multiplexer is a device that selects one of several analog or digital input signals and forwards the selected input into a single line.
[image]

For this i recommend use [74ls157](http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheet/motorola/SN54LS157.pdf). This is  Quad 2-to-1 Multiplexer.
[image]

The operation of the 74LS157, Quad 2 line to 1 line multiplexer is quite simple. It simply acts as four switches. When the A/B input is low, the A inputs are selected. E.g. 1A passes through to 1Y, 2A passes through to 2Y etc. When the A/B is high, the B inputs are selected.

Comment: "Paper out"???? This is multiplexer, but he needs a demultiplexer. This can't switch 12 V, and neither can output 1A. This is not a good answer.